# How to tell if XML element is marked as required in the XSD file

Tags: xsd, schema

I need to mark some elements as non required in the XSD schema. How do I go about figuring out which elements are marked as required, is there any particular flag I should be searching for. Currently all of my elements are marked with `minOccurs="0"`, is this what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes.

`minOccurs="0"` is what you need to add to an element as optional.
Having no `minOccurs` attribute implies mandatory (since by default `minOccurs="1"`)