# MULE ESB Simple SOAP service create mandatory fields

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, mule

I want to expose a Simple SOAP web service in Mule 3.4 Community.
Some fields of the service need to be mandatory/required. How can that be done?

Here is the web service method:

```
public String methodname(String field1, String field2, String field3);
```

Here is the resulting wsdl:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="field1" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="field2" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="field3" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
```

How can I make these fields minOccurs="1" and nillable="false"

Please note @XmlElement(required=true) doesn't work with my Java version 1.6

Answer (score 1):

`minOccurs="1"` makes the element **mandatory** and `minOccurs="0"` makes it **optional**
So make the following change to make it mandatory:-

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="field1" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="field2" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="field3" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
```

For your reference :- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f59a3ee2-5997-4ee7-8c09-8d371c923267/creating-required-elements-in-xsd?forum=xmlandnetfx

and

[How to tell if XML element is marked as required in the XSD file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769802/how-to-tell-if-xml-element-is-marked-as-required-in-the-xsd-file)

and `nillable` is specifies whether an explicit null value can be assigned to the element
reference:-http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp

So you need to make change in your WSDL so that the Java class generated from to implements those properties of attributes

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do this with a simple service (as it's simple by definition, it would probably work latter versions of java as you point).

You should switch to a fullfeatured jaxws service without autogenerated wdsl.